# Primefaces fileUpload with uploader apache-commons gets 413 Request Entity Too Large Response

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, jsf, primefaces, apache-commons-fileupload

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.4.Release, Primefaces 6.2, Java 11.

I am using the Primefaces fileuploader component where the uploader mode is set to `commons`.

Working on the test environment, when a file with size more than 10MB is uploaded, the nginx reverse proxy returns `413  Request Entity Too Large`. This is due to the configuration of the nginx `client_max_body_size=10MB`, which we want to keep. Instead of changing the configuration, using streaming for the file upload should solve our problem. However, so far I could not make streaming work such that we do not get this response 413. Here is the code:

The `application.properties` part regarding the file upload

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
joinfaces.primefaces.uploader=commons
```

I am using the p:fileupload component of Primefaces

```html
 <h:form id="documentUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" widgetVar="fileUploadButton"
                  binding="#{uploadedDoc}" mode="advanced" auto="true"
                  fileUploadListener="#{projectController.documentController.fileUploadHandler}"
                  value="#{projectController.documentController.file}"
                  sizeLimit="2147483648" label="#{msg['file.choose']}"
                  onstart="if(#{!projectController.managed}) {disableUploadButton()}"
                  oncomplete="if(#{!projectController.managed}) {enableSubmitButton()}"
                  disabled="#{projectController.documentController.hasDocument}"
                  required="true"
                  update="fileSelectionPanel">
    </p:fileUpload>
</h:form>
```

On local host the code successfully enters FileUploadFilter, MiltipartRequest. The request is parsed into fileItems. Enters CommonsFileUploadDecoder and calls `fileUploadHandler(FileUploadEvent event)`   successfully. However in the test environment the response 413 is returned somewhere before entering the `fileUploadHandler(FileUploadEvent event)`.

I would really appreciate some advice. Thank you in advance! I can provide you with any details.

Comment: How do you intend to activate the streaming which you want to surpass the 10MByte limit? FileUploads are normally simply posted or is there a new HTTP upstreaming extension I don't know about yet?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Selaron. The idea is to send the file in chunks less than 10MB limit using a library. I thought the apache-commons library would be able to do this. But reading from your comment, I understand I need to implement a custom  way to do this: separate the file to upload into chunks, send these as requests, on the server side combine the chunks. What approach would you recommend? Do you know a library I can use with primefaces for this goal? Thanks..